# SP2013 Column Validation Length without spaces

Tags: 2013, list, column, validation

I have a Column `Title`, and need to get its length but not counting any spaces.

`This is a test` should give me the length of `11`

With `LEN` I can get the length of a string, but with the spaces. After searching a little bit I had the idea to replace all spaces with blank. But there is no `Replace` Function I could use.

The `Replace` Function that is build in can't be used that way, because I can only replace a specified character (via index) with another.

But I want to go over the `Title` and replace every occurring space with blank.

How is this possible?

Comment: Did you think to add a Script Editor and check it by javascript? (before save method) Can this idea fix to you?

Comment: No JS in this case :(

Comment: You should take a look of this: https://spregex.codeplex.com/
So you can add a regex validation column. Then use this regex to check the number of characters: ( *?[0-9a-zA-Z] *?){5,5}

Comment: Does it work with 2013 as well?

Comment: Guess so. Take a look also at this: http://3sharp.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-in-sharepoint-lists/